# ICS disable sound/vibrate when keys pressed

Tags: settings, haptic-feedback

I want to disable the sound/vibrate effect when typing a message in Ice Cream Sandwich. I have disabled it in `Settings > Sound` Now there is no touch sound when I am typing a phone number or selecting an application to run, but there is still sound/vibrate when I type messages. How can I disable that too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On vanilla Android you do this by going into `Settings -> Language & Input` and then pressing the settings button to the right side of "Android Keyboard" (or, generically, whatever keyboard you're using). There are two checkboxes on the keyboard settings page, one for "Vibrate on keypress" and one for "Sound on keypress". Uncheck both of these to disable the keyboard sounds/vibration.

Answer (score 0):

To disable vibrate on the SwiftKey keyboard:

```
bring up keyboard
long-press Swiftkey/123 button
click Settings
Advanced
Typing Audio & Haptic Feedback
disable Haptic Feedback
```